# How to read a file after creating it without refreshing the project folder in Java

Tags: java, file, refresh, project

I have a java code that creates a kml file and then the front-end code wants to read the file right away. The file creation is successful. But the problem is I need to refresh the project folder from Eclipse and then it can read the file. This is very obvious to read the file in such way.

My question is how to read the file from front-end code without refreshing the project folder. Is there any techniques?

Thanks in advance......

Comment: Can you post your code that writes and reads the file ?

Comment: I write file from java code and read file from JS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the exact error is you get, but it might help if you create an empty file before the process and just append stuff during execution. That way the file is found without refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem. Just create an empty file as the same name that you used inside your code and then put 
Thread.sleep(2000);

after the file creation method.

Pretty simple :-)